# How to deploy a Java web application on raspberry pi

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

I have created a java web application using netbeans 8.
The project works fine.

I need a help to put my project to the raspberry pi , so that when i type the ip address in the web browser it should run my java web application.

Also what are the things i needed to make my raspberry pi as a web server.

In my raspberry pi ,i already have java 8 ,apache2 ,tomcat8.

Comment: Is it a question about system administration or programming?

Comment: Connect to the device via ssh, copy the war, launch tomcat. After that you should be able to use the application

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia first of all thank you for your valuable comment.......do i need to put copy whole project to the raspberry pi.....

Comment: If you have a webapp, when you compile it should generate an archive file (usually a .war) . You need to copy that to the PI and tell the tomcat inside to run that. No need to copy the source files.

Comment: of course that's under the condition that Tomcat's properly set up to provide whatever resources the application needs (database resource pools, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Tomcat8 from in /home/pi
   https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi#8.0.53
2. $ cd $HOME
3. $ tar xzf apache-tomcat-8.0.53.tar.gz
4. $ mv apache-tomcat-8.0.53 tomcat8
5. $ tar xzf tomcat8.tar.gz
6. $ cd $HOME/tomcat8/conf
7. $ sudo nano tomcat-users.xml
   add 
   add
8. $ cd $HOME/tomcat8/bin
9. $ sh startup.sh
10. Open Browser
    http://localhost:8080/manager/html
    User Name: admin
    Password: admin
11. Choose .war file under WAR file to deploy section
12. Open Browser and run your application 
    eg. http://localhost:8080/FirstJspProject/HelloWorld.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 Follow the instructions from [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04) and install tomcat.

```
Step 2 After installing in netbeans, Go to Run->Clean and build.
Step 3 Goto Project folder and find the projectname.war file in dist folder.
Step 4 Rename the war to ROOT.war.
Step 5 Assuming you have followed all the procedure as mentioned in digital 
ocean from step 1, goto http://localhost:8080/
Step 6. Click Manage App .
Step 7  At the bottom there will be a browse button under upload war. Click it
Step 8  After selecting ROOT.war . Click deploy.
```

There you go. Now enter http://ip_of_pi:8080 from any browser in local network to view your site.

[Port forward](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/general-port-forwarding-guide/) it to access it globally. (optional).

P.S :- if you find error in the line curl -O in step 1 guide , replace the step by manually downloading tomcat.tar from Tomcat Official Site.[Tomcat's Official Site](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi) to tmp folder.

Hope it helps someone